# Tool to identify the sources of compile-time memory consumption

Tags: linux, c++, compiler, static-analysis

**TLDR;** What kind of tools are available in a Unix environment to help me identify where time and memory are being spent at compile-time?

I have a small C++ hobby project which contains no template declarations, makes sparse use of headers and has (almost) all function definitions in separate compilation units for each class.

I was surprised to find that compile-time memory usage exceeded 1GB per core. I suspect this is due to my reliance on various boost libraries (but not preprocessor, mpl, fusion, or any other TMP wizardry), but have no way of knowing for sure. Compile-time is also suspiciously long.